# How to detect which external libraries/dependencies use PendingIntent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the following error in Android 12:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

I changed all of my flags to FlagImmutable, but still that error was being shown. Then I commented out all the PendingIntents inside my project and still that error was there, which made me think that external libs might be using those PendingIntents. Is there a way to detect which exact dependencies are using PendingIntents?

Comment: Right-click the constructor -> Find usages...

Comment: ^ searching is a good way to check where they're potentially used - if you want to fix this specific error, doesn't the stacktrace tell you what package is calling the code that's throwing?

Comment: Hello @benazir-sh , did you find a way?

Comment: Same issue and there is no line on my code. I guess it is a dependency that has not been updated. Any way to identify which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

The error showed up when I updated the app to Android version 13 (API 33) having some dependencies far below the latest stable.

I haven't found any way to know which dependency uses the `PendingIntent` but in the end, I managed to solve it using common sense.

In my case the library that produced the error was `androidx.work:work-runtime` but the other candidates I had in my list were `firebase`, `play-services`, etc.